# Error with a Volley RequestQueue in a subclass Singleton when posting multiple sqlite data to a remote server

Tags: sqlite, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest, request-queueing

Im developing an app that gathers attendance data and saves to sqlite (offline mode).  On a daily basis, I would like the app to post the attendance data to a remote server using Volley.  Im successful with posting a single attendance thru Volley upon submit by the user, but I would like the app to post multiple attendances (days) saved in sqlite from a single Volley subclass that is trigger in the onResume() of an activity.

The issue is that I am getting an error with the following codes as I believe I am not correctly initializing the subclass context as Application() - as I'm fairly new with Kotlin development.  I have included each part of the Kotlin files that attempts to process the post to remote server.

ATTENDANCEFRAGMENT.KT
This is the fragment activity that calls the subclass under onResume()

```
... private lateinit var dataBase: TransactionDatabase

   override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            dataBase.postTransactions()
    }
```

In my sqlite database class, I created a Select query of all Attendances for this user and within the select loop, I call the Volley singleton subclass to Post the data to the remote server:

TRANSACTIONDATABASE.KT

```
fun postTransactions() {
        val sql = "select * from $TABLE order by $COL_ID desc"
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val id = cursor.getString(0).toInt()
                val uid = cursor.getString(1).toInt()
                val clockin = cursor.getString(2)
                val clockout = cursor.getString(3)
                val customer = cursor.getString(4)
                val dateStamp = cursor.getString(5)

                 apiRequest.postTransactions(uid,clockin,clockout,customer,dateStamp)

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
```

This is my Volley singleton class:

APIREQUEST.KT

```
class ApiRequest : Application() {

    fun postTransactions(uid: Int, clockin: String, clockout: String, customer: String, dateStamp: String ) {

        val requestQueue : RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        val url = AppConstant.endpoint_url + "uid=$uid&clockin=$clockin&clockout=$clockout&customer=$customer&dateStamp=$dateStamp"
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, {
                response ->try {
            val jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("Attendance")

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }, { error -> error.printStackTrace()
            
        })

        requestQueue.add(request)
    }
```

The is the error I am getting:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
> android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
> reference

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I also found this online in GitHub that provides an example of a Volley subclass, but I am not able to successfully apply it to my app: https://google.github.io/volley/requestqueue.html

Thanks
Octavious